# How to calculate the intersection between a line and a plane programmatically?

Tags: php, algorithm, math, 3d, shared-libraries

I have a formula for a plane in 3d space

```
-2658985.48304*(x+2658985.48304)
-5346635.44099*(y+5346635.44099)
+5269212.43874*(z-5269212.43874) = 0
```

I also have a vector formula for a line in 3d space...

```
r(t) =   (  4077149.9388, 14675462.7240,-11546186.0029) 
     + t*(-10458715.0981,-27507387.7824,-24192295.8559)
```

Is there any way to programmatically calculate the intersection point between the plane and the vector in PHP (or other programming language)?

Comment: You are looking to construct a small script that allows you to calculate all points of intersection of plane (P) with a line - where, say, a plane would be defined as e.g. P =3x + 2y − z = 8 and a line defined as e.g. x = 2t, y =3+2t, z = 2t. That the basic idea? What have you tried so far? Show us your best attempt(code) so we can help you solve any issues you might be facing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is... You need to describe your plane by its normal `n` and any point `q` belonging to the plane. The normal is easy just by converting your equation to:

```
dot( n , (x,y,z) )  = D
```

where `n` is the plane normal.  The `q` must be computed by setting 2 coordinates to anything and computing the 3th however in case your plane is parallel to `xy`,`yz` or `zx` plane you need to chose the coordinates that are changing ... So chose the 2 abs smallest coordinates in normal and you should be fine.

The normal in your case is directly visible:

```
n = (2658985.48304,-5346635.44099,5269212.43874)
```

so you should generate `x,z` and compute `y` for the `q`. For simplicity let `x=z=0`...

You have your line in vector form already:

```
p(t) = p0 + t*dp
```

where `p0` is start point of your line, `dp` is `end_point-start_point` and `t` is scalar parameter in range `t=<0.0,1.0>`

from that you can use vector math to get the intersection point `p`...

```
t = dot( q-p0 , dp )
p = p0 + t*dp
```

However you need to check if the point is inside line so:

```
t >= 0.0 AND t <= 1.0
```

However in case the plane and line are parallel (can use any of these two):

```
|   dot( n , dp ) - |n|*|dp| | <= 1e-6
| cross( n , dp )            | <= 1e-6
```

You have to check the resulting point is really inside the plane simply by checking

```
| dot ( n , q ) - D | <= 1e-6
```

and that is it ...

Comment: Why did you consider that the line is a segment, i.e. that `t` lies between 0 and 1? A math line is generally infinite, I cannot see such a restriction in OP's question.

Comment: @Damien :) that has been lost in translation ... line in my language has different meaning (line is always line segment, we use (half)axis for the infinite line) anyway commenting out the condition will do the trick for infinite lines ...